# field_collection_item not updating / old data preserved

Tags: 7, entities, crm

I am using SalesForce suite to pull data from SalesForce to Drupal.

In the SalesForce object I have multiple date fields.  These fields needs to map to a field-collection in the node.  The field-collection can have multiple (unlimited) values.

So for example in the SalesForce object I have

`sales_force_object -> start_date
sales_force_object -> event_date
sales_force_object -> end_date`

which needs to map to

`node -> the_dates [0] = sales_force_object -> start_date 
node -> the_dates [1] = sales_force_object -> event_date 
node -> the_dates [2] = sales_force_object -> end_date`

The solution was to add 'temporary' fields on the node, let's call them:

`node -> sync_start_date
node -> sync_event_date
node -> sync_end_date`

When I get data from SalesForce (using pull; and yes the data comes through OK) - I map the values from the SalesForce object to the sync fields.  Then just before the node is saved (updated), I use `hook_node_presave` to take values from the sync fields and create the field-collection items.  This is the code:

```
  $fc = field_collection_item_load($key_dates_entity_id);
  $fc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $fc);
  $fc_wrapper->field_date->set((int) $date);
  $fc_wrapper->save();
  field_attach_update('node', $node);
  field_attach_presave('node', $node);
  entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache([$node->nid]);
```

You can safely assume that `$key_dates_entity_id` is the correct field-collection entity ID.

Inspecting the code I can see the entity is correctly updated (nothing wrong with the data), and when I check the MySQL general-log, I can see the data being saved to the database, **however**, when the set of instructions end, the old (cached) data is also saved.  In other words the DB is updated twice - once with the new value, and once with the old values: net result is field collection items are not updated.

I have tried all sorts of combinations - nothing works.  Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to tell you why, but I have not been able to figure it out: I just know it works.

Initially I executed the code above in `hook_node_presave($node)`, but obviously it did not work.  So I figured I should try `hook_node_update($node)` - but that did not work either.

Then I discovered `drupal_register_shutdown_function` and now my `hook_node_update` looks like this:

```
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type === 'node_type') {
    drupal_register_shutdown_function('_update_from_sync_fields', $node);
  }
}
```

`node_type` is the type of node I am checking against.  Any case, once the node is actually saved - that is all processing is done, db transactions completed, etc - drupal will call my shutdown function.  Now when I update the field values, and in specific field-collection fields - they are saved.

Of-course saving these fields and calling:

```
  field_attach_update('node', $node);
  field_attach_presave('node', $node);
  entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache([$node->nid]);
```

at the end of my shut-down function triggers hook_node_update again, but fortunately I have a token that tells me - so I do not execute the code again.

This solution works - what I am not happy about is the fact that it executes when Drupal is shutting down.

I think the problem is related to the fact that node_save starts a DB transaction, and when I update related entity (field-collection) items in `hook_node_save` or `hook_node_presave` I am starting another (nested) transaction.  Clearly my transaction updating field-collection items completes, but when the outer (first) transaction then complete, it is writing old/dirty data.

The trick is going to be to clear the dirty data from cache.  I was hoping `entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache([$node->nid]);` would do that - but clearly it does not?

So next I changed the `hook_node_update` to :

```
function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type === 'node_type') {
    _update_from_sync_fields ($node);
  }
}
```

in other words - from `hook_node_update` I simply call the 'shut-down`function, then I rebuilt the drupal registry (`drush rr`) and voila - it worked.  Now I am even more confused.  It is possible that my original code worked all along, but there was something wrong with the registry (or caches).  All things being equal, all the examples I read was right.

From hook_node_update, load the field collection entity, update and save the entity.  The clear the caches and do a `field_attached_presave` and `field_attached_update` like so:

```
  entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache([$node->nid]);
  field_attach_presave('node', $node);
  field_attach_update('node', $node);
```